# What is the order of clearing elements from std::list?

Tags: c++, list, stl

I want to clear the contents of some `std::list`. The order of removing of elements is important for me. According to output of the following test program, the order is from first to last element. Is it guaranteed to be so? It was not clear for me from C++2003 standard.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  A(int i) : I(i) {}
  ~A() { std::cout << I << std::endl; }
  int I;
};

int main()
{
  std::list<A> l;
  l.push_back(A(1));
  l.push_back(A(2));
  l.push_back(A(3));

  std::cout << "clearing list" << std::endl;
  l.clear();
}
```

[ideone link](http://ideone.com/wcOSZ)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why is the removing order important to you?

Comment: If it is that important to you you can use erase() to erase them one after the other manually.

Comment: @GabrielSchreiber: … or `pop_front()`.

Comment: @nietaki: The order is important because some objects use references, which are invalidated by others. First, I have to remove those who use references and then those who invalidate.

Comment: I was expected that the order will be defined, since it is _sequence_ container. It seems the best reliable way to preserve the order is to use `pop_front()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not defined, and you should not rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not defined.

The standard only specifys that whenever you call `a.clear()` it will be resolved as `a.erase(q1,q2)` and it just specify's the erase will erase all the elements in the range `[q1,q2)`  but it does not specify the order in which it will do so.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, the C++11 standard does not determine the order of destruction of any `sequence containers`, of which `std::list` is a member. It only states that all the elements are destroyed, all references, pointers and iterators referring to the elements are invalidated, and the past the end iterator *may* be invalidated. Concerning `clear()`, it makes no mention of `erase()`, `begin()` or `end()`, unlike hte C++03 standard.

Answer (score 0):

From c++03 standard:

> Table 67—Sequence requirements (in addition to container) 
>   ...
>
> a.clear()
>
> assertion/note: void erase(begin(), end())
>
> post: size() == 0.

Since it starts deleting elements from "begin" I think is safe to infers that they will be deleted in order. Otherwise will be a performance penalty to random access list elements.

Comment: I don't think it is a safe assumption, since erase(q1, q2) doesn't say anything about the order of destruction of the elements.